# birt viewer dynamic parameters

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, combobox, reporting, birt

im using birt reorting tool. when i use dynamic parameter as combobox, its values are not loading when we hosted live. in locally its working fine. simply when i change to my server profile dat files this happen.

but if i used normal static parameteres all are working fine.

this is my server profile dat file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><DataTools.ServerProfiles version="1.0"><profile autoconnect="No" desc="" id="f8e38600-460b-11e0-ae87-e29247985a12" name="CommonHRMData" providerID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc"><baseproperties><property name="odaURL" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.108:3306/hr_mysql_common"/><property name="odaDriverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/><property name="odaPassword" value="hsenidsoft"/><property name="odaUser" value="root"/><property name="contentBidiFormatStr" value="ILYNN"/><property name="metadataBidiFormatStr" value="ILYNN"/></baseproperties><org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.versionInfo><property name="technology.version.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" value="3.0.6"/><property name="server.version" value="5.1.0.7"/><property name="technology.name.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" value="DTP Open Data Access"/><property name="server.name" value="MySQL"/></org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.versionInfo></profile></DataTools.ServerProfiles>
```

regards
roshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This you server profile dat file you can edit the current db location

or yuou can edit you xml file of the report and give the path manualy

```
<property name="technology.name.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" value="DTP Open Data Access"/><property name="server.name" value="MySQL"/></org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.versionInfo></profile></DataTools.ServerProfiles>
```